# MacBook Air's Mini Display vs Thunderbolt

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I can't find the right info on this, everything that I'm reading is mostly about monitors and HDMI about this topic.

So my questions is... can I run an ethernet adapter for internet access through a 2010 MBA model that has the Mini Display Port or is this only a capability with the Thunderbolt replacement port for the 2011 MBA models?

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible with the Thunderbolt port. You cannot run an ethernet adapter on a Mini Display Port.

However, you can use a USB Ethernet Adapter and connect to your network with that.

Comment: but isn't the Thunderbolt port the same shaped port in the same place when it replaced the regular mini Display port from the 2010 to the 2011 model?

Comment: The connector is physically the same and in the same place on the computer. Electrically they are completely different though, and not compatible. You can under no circumstances use a Thunderbolt adapter in a Mini-DisplayPort-only port.